# Print the new site header

Tags: code-golf, string, kolmogorov-complexity

The new site header has some bits of source code from various questions as the background. Here are the first 3 lines:

```
--<-<<+[+[<+>--->->->-<<<]>]<<--.<++++++.<<-..<<.<+.>>.>>.<<<.+++.>>.>>-.<<<+. Hello, World! IT'S SHOWTIME TALK TO THE HAND "Hello, World!" YOU HAVE BEEN TERMINATED "9!dlroW ,olleH"ck,@ 72a101a+7aa+3a44a32a87a111a+3a-6a-8a33a Take Circle Line to Paddington Take Circle Line to Wood Lane Take Circle L
alert'Hello, World!' target byteorder little;import puts;export main;section"data"{s:bits8[]"Hello, World!\0";}foreign"C"main(){foreign"C"puts("address"s);foreign"C"return(0);} aeeeaeeewueuueweeueeuewwaaaweaaewaeaawueweeeaeeewaaawueeueweeaweeeueuw H class H{public static void main(String[]a){System.
World!");}}+[-->-[>>+>-----<<]<--<---]>-.>>>+.>>..+++[.>]<<<<.+++.------.<<-.>>>>+. "Hello, World!"o| :after{content:"Hello, World!" H;e;P1;@/;W;o;/l;;o;Q/r;l;d;2;P0 ('&%:9]!~}|z2Vxwv-,POqponl$Hjihf|B@@>,=<M:9&7Y#VV2TSn.Oe*c;(I&%$#"mCBA?zxxv*Pb8`qo42mZF.{Iy*@dD'<;_?!\}}|z2VxSSQ main(){puts("Hello, W
```

However, a few microseconds of extra load time can cause the user to click away from the site, so the page header download really should be optimized as much as possible.

Write a program that takes no input and produces the (first 3 lines of) text from the new header as output.

- Trailing newline is optional
- Must include the line breaks from the original header
- [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so shortest code wins!

Comment: I'm cautiously hopeful that the patchwork of kinds of text in the header will encourage more tailored approaches than the generic text compression methods that plague kolmogorov complexity challenges.

Comment: @xnor Yeah, there are multiple "Hello, World"s, but then the BF and evil likely have their own interesting compression.

Comment: Just an FYI the naive bubblegum answer is 594 bytes.

Comment: @FryAmTheEggman I get 588

Comment: That `System.alert` is triggering

Comment: What header is this? Mine appears to start with [`Circle`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G3DpO.png).

Comment: @Mast Inspect element on the header and look at the css background-img. It's a bit clearer if you look at the header from the meta site.

Comment: @DanielM. Oops, just saw that. Comment deleted.

Answer (score 19):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), <s>601</s> <s>584</s> <s>574</s> <s>564</s> <s>553</s> 539 [bytes](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax/blob/master/docs/packed.md#packed-stax)

```
«=¬█j▼sw│╥═7♫çÿñ╦*‼e"!‼╤Å╟D·εWÜå╖L♂@#î╚å♫▐ô;(┤┼»Kî→δäû║h◘│¶zurΘ█┐£ë}∞è┼$÷gôwg¬≤╒Ñ╧]∙ì▄╦╕ís│\☺'┴♫Φ^┐╤å{1█♠₧ï∩∙↑▀⌂d▲╡⌡3J‼¡qâ╧3¥Çƒwe▀≡╔MjZΣΩyüO╬ªÉΩö^Y╡►8K₧óN·ÿjg≈Cö9^◘■~Ä_ßx▐Å┌ Q>/♫╤QΩzN╤V½▓▀◙ß╗╗◄►(╔☺╡┘Ah╙¢√ß▼GΩ→ù◄:─◘#♫úq•ø≤>↨)Å│╤[ïmgBX┤╛v\ⁿ╛å╘╕7d╪TµbW#2¶ø╙╜~êê[↨>K►♪0∞#XJ°ñntG∞⌐V♥Z<ÿº'║☺;┤é⌡♠gáσßÑ+♂z♥‼S9 l≈╫ºÜT»↕▀τ♣¡gWe¥_çà(┬f╜n[╗╤fσ╞R₧▲V▌═◙úKÆÜ▄☺╥s1▼╩ûû╗▌▌Ω■g∞Y╡9╦tè┴y♂w∟⌂┌'╣W▀M╓·uBôúPm◘ ☻ⁿFh<╘sú▲Ö╘¶¿_2♦Θb{╪δC\lô+▀9¶ß§╡╓)ú}○8∟⌡nÑôI )╓îFbH[î║╞e&"¶↓~A#ç╔▄─áσ∙:═Æ▬ª▄ÄêQSNM◙∞Z╜≈±╘▬LIÿ|#.¿Φµ║▌Lväv▓♣;└Æ▲▄♣↕{╪½)╚φ╡♦:oÉ▀j╠ΔP<ç↔|±╦=╣▓Φ▒─4D▄■ìà>↓┐
```

[Run and debug it](https://staxlang.xyz/#p=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&i=&a=1)

It does at least attempt to use different strategies for different pieces.
I've still got some hope for a few sections, but here's an explanation of the approaches so far.

```
                                    The general approach is to push a bunch of stuff on the stack. 
                                    Then join it all together and split it in thirds.
'                                   just a space
`jaH1"jS3!`X                        compressed literal for "Hello, World!" assigned to the x register
`38dZl;i#D]|@Y@*`                   compressed literal for "It's showtime talk to the hand"
^                                   convert to upper case; it compresses better in lower case
n'"|SY                              Wrap the x register in quotes and save it in the y register
`=j("sx6c1 ob`^                     compressed literal for "you have been terminated" in upper
."9                                 literal for '"9'
yrD                                 register y (quoted hello world), reversed, first character dropped
"ck,@ "                             literal
"^h{ai{W>bJ,^T+NLDK(G$s@+"!         crammed array [725, 101597559, 354, 45325875, 1115935, -65, -85335]
$"5a9+"|t                           concat as strings, then map '5' to 'a' and '9' to '+'
`='9%[mh++PxF!`                     compressed literal for " Take Circle Line to "
`~J@[E<`n                           compressed literal for "Paddington"; copy the one about the circle
`jj_kmZ5`                           compressed literal for "Wood Lane"
n7T                                 copy " Take Circle Line to " and truncate last 7 characters
"alert'"x''                         some literals and x register
`~lLKPq'III^) .tI:G8?uMolVwpnT&u#`  compressed literal with commas in place of semi-colons
.,;|t                               replace with semi-colons, which aren't allowed in compressed literals
`/zOXzN`",data,{s:bits8[],`x\0_;}`cC,main(){`cC,puts(,address,s);` C,return(0);} ".,"|t
                                    compressed literal for "foreign", followed by a string template
"Nm\{<\3VdH,FF:c~7&u!n"96|E         carefully chosen string literal interpreted in base 96
"eawu":B                            encoded in custom base "eawu"   
`dzJxVHC"`'{`pS7yzeENLM%_'`         two compressed literals with a '{' in the middle
"(String[]a){System."               literal
x6)                                 last 6 characters of register x
"`");}}"                            literal with escaped uote
"0;pKll>r&.sSP}JLNL==(>eP>-2\6fc8|)4&.:,1jA66O{t0>GpALk4I{.iDM:Gr_50ga"
90|E                                literal of ascii characters decoded in base 90
"[+-><],.":B                        re-encoded with a custom base of brainfuck
72:/                                split at position 72
~                                   push the right half to the input stack, effectively the beginning
" `yo| :after{content:`y H;e;P1;@/;W;o;/l;;o;Q/r;l;d;2;P0 ('&%:9]!~}|z2Vxwv-,POqponl$Hjihf|B@@>,=<M:9&7Y#VV2TSn.Oe*c;(I&%$#`"mCBA?zxxv*Pb8``qo42mZF.{Iy*@dD'<;_?!\}}|z2VxSSQ main(){puts("
                                    big string template including y register a few times
y9(                                 first 9 characters of y
Lr$                                 wrap all stacks in array and concatenate
3Mm                                 split into 3 equal parts and print as lines
```

Comment: Please do add a description of the strategies you employed.

Comment: Nice, thanks for the breakdown!

Comment: That `yo| :after{content` make it look like some kind of rap.

Answer (score 14):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 568 bytes

```
“¢lẊḊ%ñẇÄNị¡ẸVþṾɲXØ?^ÆÐX⁷®bWċ’b7ị“-+[>].<”” “3ḅaė;œ»©“×;-¢İiĖƝÞth⁴"Ạ⁺Xṙ{»Œu®“JṁkKɼġʋḲỴ9|ḤḲ»Œu®U“ƭJ&çȯ»” Ȯø“¡ŻAÆ¡ ⁾Ʋ⁵(S0-’b122_⁵ȯ€“”ṭ"3,5,10Ṭ×”+¤j”a“Æ¬>hPḢ¤Ġ2fɠjẆȤ¬ṬwḷÇRy_ỴṬƓO¶~^YG³ẸṂḊỤÇ»®“¡ñA¦ɗɱṪḅạðEṘ/Ḋ_³ṢÑ⁺ċßs³m0>*Ḥıo7Ʋ>[;ɼ⁽¢OẆ9Ɓ€»®“¤Z!ƤḂĊlðiƝṘŻqọ6³Ṣṡḃ8Þœn⁶ʠẉ>yuẆ{»Ḳj“ṢẈ,ẊL»” ø“×©K⁸ƁƬ÷FġƬṘ¹^Ẉ§ṭƁḅ’b4ị“wuae”“£¦ƊNỴŻw;ƊFɦȦnœĠÐẇṀu½X*ṠOJ8ȷḍu&)ṫ)⁼ẏµ×ẏ`ȯ»ø“¡-P⁽Rȯ$@°ḤėXƙ€ṭ⁶Vė7-²ɦ{NỌQ’b7ị“+-><].[”⁾ "®“ıȷ®⁻ʂ£Þȷ⁹ṣp°⁷»®ø“Ṛ|ġcßỵiṃ^ɱrÐẏNạŀiUĠ¥ĿSʂĊ⁷Ð+¦ŻvIṖj~ż¹kĿƥð¿ƘeḶZƤLɱ ṭṡ¥⁷ė$ ėƬ ċ⁵Ṛ¿⁷¢²_ṛż⁽p£⁽n#/i½ɱ`M3BƓḳ?¥ạuẹ09ʠ;"J!ṢIMkIoÐȯ²&_ẋẓṗḲ>½Q>ẈȯĠ ŀJṇḢC.(Eı’b128ịØJ“¡ʂh;⁼µ:ȮçṛƤb7ḋ2ṢR»
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TZMNTxNZFIb/SkWXqFBE2F3AmrpqdEP9QDG6VSIVNxgKLLqrXUI0plN3QVuNuE2csiJOS6lxt0KnUDp3ho/k3Ds3M/0XZ/4Ie6ZosslkZu7NOfe853nPHR@dnJzZ2/OSi1CYRDONRvobrqM5x/@4jFYG8mgaN/gOsh23GuW5U8N8ls9HPaUOq3d/EhkvuXC3h@IoP9g2FL7dcdJLvqcnQBvdaPw5ItSQnQULPtEGV0NBKIhKXLyV7/nSozFP2WhBU/MUM4ps4TFY9l8JWKXICDJl4oK7JfKNDBpVtDb6nqBRpN8vMdcpSH6OtPKPzhpYfkFnlRt@F3nbOs1nIR/wlB1Z9ZTa4WudQV/m8a6uGC2dNS9VpkDKQfa5pbv9u/bjncjKXKWdNiiO02fEFzsL5fDYFTQKUBRa1z1XG0dz1ilCmYKn0ajzucGZGCmjpcwOwObT4Zs/wjrhQpYiimgV@Rw1vtoUxfXTUHJVV0f2D2FBM88r55DljlFkjLJYgb8hDCLDPzyE9V86w0epXaHf75HV8FDI3fKUbSgMkIA@qZD@r@cWbx2QRCUl0pO8EpfUUc62fkXr1ffNM5Hl0XjWy5fs7JSnbDY0NF@EZxJ0DLEmmNTroh9mPm8n6y/ug2xi5Cp8uuAphlRkmdfPi7yktnPAhikWPhI4qVAbPtZv992fToyMNq1fhGUoyTQNz4ZtTYdk@rxbckpTdlZofJ7mClkyAdvRo8i0gUivU0fjVaL1CLJ/j3jKFpqvocZV@tzxff3iaPAKtT/orB36ASo@FjUqFwgCqaCmbgi1JwhVt/SYSr68@r@BbAuGT97uGPJVKTuBliYxoTs0uZ5iNVKwzJecuqcwZMsPoOKPNFFtlkT29xOR/5l/QKsWR/Zs2NV/88W/vkzG2cn4daHBiti91iDwlMfn26BkW7/3I3s7/tTeAjYhduUKr8CuzI2isXlLFi@6eoAEkyOwQilCPRQQqiwH6AopNaoHu76AAlRjyN7Zvt8PYJneUwePxWHb1e9c6j4js2isn4IVEkEess6@hhZqiRwgB/svTfTf5/PErNoaQzODZhaZSg6HYftqmDxz1oQWsJN0r@Zoos92HD4n9P1L0UuweC7SBN1IjYXIBaidoNtELr@TRYJpZLqoxCBYe3v/AQ)

I tried to add optimizations per section. The optimized string compressor compresses this to 730 bytes (which *should* be the best possible just using basic Jelly syntactical constructs rather than any actual methods), so it appears I have done something.

(Fun fact: after I posted this answer, Chrome started suggesting translating this page to Vietnamese :P)

Comment: Interestingly enough, pasting your full answer into google translate detect language uses Igbo. It "translates" the part corresponding to `œ»©“×;-¢İiĖƝÞth⁴"Ạ⁺Xṙ{` as "the rest", but then if I paste that substring by itself, it detects as Viatnamese and translates to gibberish.

Comment: @DanielM. Huh, that's interesting. Wonder why it recommended Vietnamese then; probably based on the Stax answer and the surrounding English. Thanks for sharing!

Answer (score 13):

## [SOGL V0.12](https://github.com/dzaima/SOGLOnline), <s>542</s> 527 [bytes](https://github.com/dzaima/SOGL/blob/master/chartable.md)

```
Hello, World!”³³"ī←≥/ī⁹βņ	fi▼pΛtι¤Υ8Th4ΚT~v‛θ5→č■⌡‘o"′]◄⅟ō&÷2}≠Θ←⁷┌∙‽↓æ³ΘZ°β╔¶ļ¹‘U┌⁷ŗo±"ē‛V)≥u∆↕]ē׀~σφ‰τ┘^|i≡»┼y3┐X3Η‛Χ4±2‘o"ΣΤ°ε⁵↑p$J↑³∫ū²▼!⁄B²⌠3τ}σS⁷bu¹1∆Ν²‘ū#Ƨtoŗo"JνΠ◄ī÷$λ⅜Zø@Pθθ╚XΔBPø√:┘¦z#│y⁹oΣ⁄½Λ'7⅞Fģ′σv+&≥μ_¦≠⅔v]lπlsβ╥^D#,℮⁾§Aα‛ķκņ▼%ķW═g!ōΜ¬`}⅛čņ█≠⁄⅔‛mZÆ~⁴πzWl─xτ▼'Η↓#ΗΩ►φL8!Ƨ:e¡′ž|Τr^+≡▒GπεΓW≥7±λxw׀ Κν⁷cP\ιYΤp|A╝æƧO∑b►\÷Q²OΟč⅔⁽(╬( ρn⁽BoG=Υ→m▒‽¤/►iΟ√PqΩ∙φ4√VΥæl‽υΧ$f0╬Dkμ⌠Lāč¾↓′∫Ε╚Βæ║↑Ν▲γB#⁶5⁹B|l↔ƨ╗6Σŗ⁄⅟ω±μξydA┼*ģ⁴Z►xa^■7O═ģΖ4Γ⅞6═¾χ‰⁷‛[‚⅓D⅞π▓z⁶‼Æņ2Υ√θ']7┐⁰īS╗<čfφ┘lθ⁄{=æ⁹Δ<¡⁾Υ□ι¹λzFΗ▲-β▒╤ÆAΩ/xff⁰ΞΠIæ┘*⁾h⁷╗ΧG─`⁾⁄@p*‘p
```

[Try it here!](https://dzaima.github.io/SOGLOnline/?code=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_,v=0.12)

Almost all compression, but broken up every now and then because English compression works only on lowercase words and case is important. I still [had to](https://tio.run/##xVZbUxNJFH7e/hXDgNxCAgQ0mAkRkFK03AILF5QQ1iZpYJZJJiYTwr0mK8xClVSpuSGIYHFbC2tLQLnI5WGS8Nh59L3/CHsmrFXr8s5OZjpz@pw@ffo73d8ZD/YP4dD5Od9CJEmu4DrloOQtYOqSvqvvIvMVXjCZw@xwmFwml8PkhA5n/udwONxOt8NhNlscpvxlAcECDcgWp9O4wcZiKPKS2RBNFlRfXx8kobCkhDjRb0d8ZotpL9nseiW8RA/pTlb7qU9kyeMAXVToob5G1@seDdTShUeTQ0xdpAfXmfY6M8eSK@zFe6bOy1cLBmfmkKiUhLjQgBxBiugjnIKlQU6ROWWAcAPY70Ucb@Y5NCKHQRwiXC8hfk4hQZ/oxwrxXgKAqTtulppi08vZueL0vnWCza7QeQOU6D6Lv2Azb5h6wrRYekPfpfNd@ie6wxJxfS9zrB8CAL8YNtH9bOqqkeBvZlO8Z7CigUM2K66uqsYmG8amGlxbi2usuM6Gq6urDdl8A5vrcE0N/u/S9W0@E4OkdpRB/sNsRmNawp2JfVMnc89zGlM/5aZYfL5nXGSz7/UjFj8eqWHxl49raMrYCZu1@rb1f9gBSMGDhPOIQY9EOEn0E47nAtjrFf39igyZvqyNyLKXk7Cf/KhE@t6lzUBX6Rpk@AuLfmHaq0DRfWj1XTazld3Sd@BUFLDoVBO8vVipyU1N5J63Q@p7w/phNaBHl0Chzme3Cs82FfnKNwSWSFBBJdlUiQFRsJ8oXO@IQpAc9JIgQKEoEkECEn0BOahwgbASAokM5yUfFv0ghYhHEWU/4pEXKxjxYyF7r6iE6lxuPpvqruKFCdQnB4nYDya3eWNQadnYv7tQ3m0pjyAfgGsI8aEy4QeDIFHCQT8qrSoTJjiECSHGEwmTcJhECAkbdySCMY4QjEkEQxvJay7scF4k@R5s9MLACOJaOOSRMMzHtYxBDL2S6OFCClbgb0gWvRfrK21XgrBJXG5cNtY@ElKIz6LvXRA7D9FMIJPLYFeX05nnWeBdh9thsK/Z7Ab6dEK/QaUGpbosBvf@Q68X@Ofp15k3grMJR1Me5@wI9wHzoDHkkf0K8SvIbmg41CIQoa1aaKgUOgVZqJQEaB9WBgVJ8ApWoQ1VcaUlxdfsN90FkxPjo9aO4ciQuaKt9VlA9ktFLb@JA33jTQ0Nzop6x8/2m8W2J4UdHdZH7X5LKyn3CKX3iq8VFfK@202Nt0aHh4fK23rrnj6Ta62@rjuWsXsj5Q3e5hKH8Outgu6JC@/t7Q85dIFR2dj3HH6vfJfOyH16QleAMTNb6f0iesSm33alDxra6AE9YImFxzTe1JY@YDMLdiAPfWO0kMV/H4HSItNVODz6CV0ssbHpd3cyq8C8uedDpmJgH3r8q74BxMum40NuKadKIYNl13uaCyvY1F8seqpvNtJtoJ3MPv2a1eAkXsvsd7LEy/6C7Bx9q398OsGmFzNzhmrG8BMFQo@Dva8rrU2y6OecOtopsbg6DJyWPC4BCtNihTRFP7Dk15z2oK7gbNNOdKhoO9nTcboW7DEB6bHk67s5lX6hsU6I0aZv06PhyDeVowv0BA6@p62bHj6ha4HxRpZYSm@cbbaymVe94LE7vf9Q32mly1ApIYzoSSlLfCzlclE/vDfJd@vpOpRRH/iH2qKvVcIQkS4DZm3PIKKZNzmtFoQOup7ekMAiN003i/qqwEfzID0G8nmQiWbm9FNYAwQM7EQTgDx9nd5giVfAWHSJJXfoblMhi@5dB@ibxiWmxc/@ZInUDbqaTeXRWc7NwoKO6emItxG4vRzyEf3cBZEM4x4o77ZWQDezSpO1NAbpugGSfpr7A6qCURfVRRdTF9h0rBl0OZUlY6MwF1OP01pWs8LqZhboQYnbBvWCRT9lttphakdmrg/KSnxego0SnRqrh3DhiyPuANijpzAm@R4@OA7p0egdSE9yxwxbAABKrKW1RvqhcrivD1zRd3TlHgyMz5fDoAEjlkSKbt6F1D6FDvDbECgHFg6g8/O/AQ) split the text up in compressible parts though.

This finally made me fix a bug in the compressor, making it unresponsive sometimes (the result still works in the previous versions though)

Answer (score 3):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language), 793 bytes

```
--<-<<+[+[<+>--->->->-<<<]>]<<--.<6*+.<<-..<<.<+GG.<<<.+++GG-.<<<+. ^ IT'S SHOWTIME TALK TO THE HAND "^" YOU HAVE BEEN TERMINATED "9!dlroW ,olleH"ck,@ 72a101a+7aa+3a44a32a87a111a+3a-6a-8a33aXine to PaddingtonXine to Wood LaneX¶alert'^' target byteorder little;import puts;export 5;section"data"{s:bits8[]"^\0";}J5(){Jputs("address"s);Jreturn(0);} aeeeaeeewueuueweeueeuewwaaaweaaewaeaawueweeeaeeewaaawueeueweeaweeeueuw H class H{public static void 5(String[]a){System.¶World!");}}+[-->-[>>+>5*-<<]<--<---]>-G>+G..+++[.>]4*<.+++.6*-.<<-G>>+. "^"o| :after{content:"^" H;e;P1;@/;W;o;/l;;o;Q/r;l;d;2;P0 ('&%:9]!~}|z2Vxwv-,POqponl$Hjihf|B@@>,=<M:9&7Y#VV2TSn.Oe$*c;(I&%$#"mCBA?zxxv$*Pb8`qo42mZF.{Iy$*@dD'<;_?!\}}|z2VxSSQ 5(){puts("Hello, W
5
main
G
.>>
J
foreign"C"
X
 Take Circle L
\^
Hello, World!
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NZHrVtpAEMe/5ymGiHIJiVwF2TSCSglWBUsKWgztQFabGrKYLAZF@lg@gC9GN3g8uzvzn5mds5dfQLnrY2GzkVRVV3VdGSkjXTFUVTW2Q9d127B1XVU1/SCraEJpwmi60m4Lr2uKIpQaS0WDMXSsVB/6ZndodS5aYDXPv4HVBctsgdm8PAV5LMNN94cIBi04brUuwWp9v@hcNq2WKB4mHC9gQ8gxz6OmPH3INaBaxEK@gEoVUSlhuYylItaqWCgU4lg9QLWGpRJeuz4FzqCHjuP695z5n5khYw6co0@v39/QowFPjVPAMbinHCbPnLLAoQF4LuceJe5szgIO8wUPCV1udYWEdMpd5ssOcpRXYX3i8rA2suXxbV4m67NKOrM6izvSsjg8oGEohxlyFlC@CPx0PkPWgJTSeEULuljQiNJFPKMIESOKSCMUNtpWPvbhNqTbDMZZ0RiBCVMPwxDM1Xwx8dwphBy5cE/MdaCS7vNAPH1kY2bVfw45nWnvb0MWeE5CFpdYK6MY6sgwFKOSFWBtPUauqrahtg2lrcUoR5phl7NbqtpBNsYqaoYgK8CxV6jjHafBasp8Tn1ej2mahJJegTT2yZAwsu8RYa/2A@IRhxRJLw/p1N5u/dBO/Fu/vhQHy@hJzfW6j3Pme0nzr/vn7vW40TByX/SL@uFe9WZnMChafV/r0mR2StKdvd3kjjw7OW4evSyXT8lsb1L7/cjKxdnPr9qq85zMNpzTlE5@HSVu1x8H9PtXECP5IGJSz2M5GEoVaYauL7UlzTCkM@mOBdS99@UTWbqWwMIHCiduMPUonEu3Y@mzbft7m81/) Well, I tried. The desired output uses all but five printable ASCII characters, but fortunately I could only find five strings with enough repetition to be worth compressing. There are also four characters repeated more than three times in a a row; these are run length encoded. Would be 1 byte longer in Retina 0.8.2 as the four run length encodings cost an extra byte each but it's then no longer necessary to quote the three desired `*`s.

Answer (score 0):

## Deadfish~, 6462 bytes

```
{iiii}iiiiicc{i}iiiiic{d}dddddc{i}iiiiicc{dd}iiic{iiiii}ddc{ddddd}iic{iiiii}ddc{ddd}dc{dd}iiic{ii}dc{dd}iiiccc{ii}dddc{dd}iiic{ii}dddc{dd}iiic{ii}dddc{dd}iiic{i}iiiiiccc{iii}iiic{ddd}dc{iii}ic{ddd}dddcc{d}dddddccic{i}iiiic{dd}iiicccccciiic{i}iiiicc{d}dddddcicc{i}iiiicc{d}ddddc{i}iiiic{dd}iiiciiic{i}iiiiiicc{d}ddddddc{i}iiiiiicc{d}ddddddc{i}iiiiccc{d}ddddcdddccciiic{i}iiiiiicc{d}ddddddc{i}iiiiiicc{dd}iiicic{i}iiiiccc{dd}iiiciiic{d}ddddc{iiii}c{iii}dc{i}dddcciiic{{d}iii}iiic{d}ddc{iiiii}iiiiic{ii}iiiiciiicddddddc{d}iic{{d}iii}iiicdc{iiii}ic{i}ic{dddd}dddddc{iiii}iiiic{ddddd}dc{iiiii}ic{d}dc{i}dddc{i}ddcdddc{d}dciiiic{d}iic{dddd}iiic{iiiii}iic{dd}ic{i}icdc{dddd}dddc{iiiii}iicdddddc{ddddd}iiic{iiiii}iic{d}ddcdddc{dddd}iiic{iiii}c{d}iiic{i}iiic{d}c{ddd}ddddddciic{iiii}ddc{iii}dc{i}dddcciiic{{d}iii}iiic{d}ddc{iiiii}iiiiic{ii}iiiiciiicddddddc{d}iic{{d}iii}iiicicddc{iiiiii}dddc{d}ciiiiiic{ddddd}dddc{iiii}c{d}iiic{ii}ic{dd}iiic{dddd}iiic{iii}iiiiciiicc{i}dc{dddd}ddddddc{iiiii}iic{d}dddddc{i}iiicdddddcddddciiiiic{d}dddc{ii}dc{d}dddddcdc{ddd}ddddddciic{ii}iiic{dd}ddddc{{i}ddd}dddc{i}ddciiiiiicdddc{dd}ddddc{ddddd}dddddc{i}iic{{i}ddd}dddcdddcc{d}iiic{ddd}ic{dddd}iic{iiiiii}iiiiic{i}ddc{dddddd}dddc{ii}c{ddd}ddc{ii}iiicdddddc{iiiii}dddc{ddddd}iicdcic{iiiii}ddc{ddddd}ddddc{i}iic{iiii}iicc{ddddd}ddddc{i}ddc{iiii}iiiiiic{dddd}dddddcc{iiii}iiiiic{dddd}ddddddcdc{iiiii}dddc{dddd}dcdc{iiii}iic{ddddd}iiccc{iiiii}ddc{ddddd}ddddc{i}ddc{iiii}iiiiiic{ddddd}ddc{i}dc{iiii}iiic{ddddd}ddc{i}ic{iiii}ic{dddd}ddddddcc{iiii}iiiiiic{dddddd}dddddc{iiiii}iic{i}iiic{i}cddddddc{{d}iii}ic{iii}iiiiic{iiii}ddc{i}dc{d}dddddc{i}dc{d}iiic{{d}iii}ic{iiii}iiiic{iii}dciiiiic{d}ic{{d}iii}ic{{i}dd}iiiicdddddc{{d}ii}ic{iiiii}ddc{ii}dddciiicciiiiiciiiiic{d}iiic{i}iiicdddddcdc{{d}ii}iic{iiiii}iic{i}iiic{i}cddddddc{{d}iii}ic{iii}iiiiic{iiii}ddc{i}dc{d}dddddc{i}dc{d}iiic{{d}iii}ic{iiii}iiiic{iii}dciiiiic{d}ic{{d}iii}ic{{i}dd}iiiicdddddc{{d}ii}ic{iiiii}iiiiic{ii}iiiicc{d}dc{{d}iii}iic{iiii}iiiic{ii}ic{i}iiic{d}ic{{d}iii}ic{iiiii}iic{i}iiic{i}cddddddc{{d}iii}ic{iii}iiiiic{iiii}ddc{i}dc{d}dddddc{i}dc{d}iiic{{d}iii}ic{iiii}iiiic{ii}ic{i}ic{d}iiic{i}iiiciic{{d}ii}iiic{iii}iiic{iii}dc{i}dddcciiic{{d}iii}iiic{d}ddc{iiiii}iiiiic{ii}iiiiciiicddddddc{d}iic{{d}iii}iiiciiiiiic{d}iiic{{i}dd}iiiic{dd}ic{ii}dddc{d}dcddc{i}iiiiic{{d}ii}ddddc{iiiiii}iiiiiic{ii}iiicdddddc{d}dddddc{i}ciiic{d}ddddcic{i}iiic{{d}ii}ddc{{i}ddd}iiiiiicdddc{i}icc{d}iic{d}iiic{dddd}ddc{iiii}iiiiiiciiiiciiicdciiiciic{{d}ii}ddddc{{i}dd}ciiiiicdcdc{ddddd}ddddddc{iiii}iic{ii}dc{d}iicdciiiciic{{d}ii}ddddc{{i}dd}dddc{d}ddc{i}ddciiiiic{ddddd}dc{iiiii}iiiiiic{d}ddddcddc{ii}dddc{d}dciiiiiicdc{{d}iii}ddddddc{iiiiii}iiiiiicdddc{ii}dc{dd}ic{dddddd}dddc{{i}d}dc{d}iic{dddddd}iiic{iiii}c{i}dddc{i}icdc{dddddd}ic{iii}iiiiiciic{dddddd}ic{iiii}ddc{iii}dc{i}dddcciiic{{d}iii}iiic{d}ddc{iiiii}iiiiic{ii}iiiiciiicddddddc{d}iic{{d}iii}iiic{iiiiii}dc{dddd}ddddc{d}ddddc{ii}iiiiic{iiiiii}iiiiiic{dd}dddc{i}dciiic{d}dddciiiicddc{i}dddc{{d}iii}ddddddc{iii}iiic{ddd}dddc{{i}ddd}iiiiic{d}ddc{i}ddciiiiic{{d}iii}cic{{i}dd}iic{dd}dc{i}dciiic{d}dddciiiicddc{i}dddc{{d}iii}ddddddc{iii}iiic{ddd}dddc{{i}dd}ddciiiiicdcdc{{d}iii}dddddcddddddc{iiiiii}iiiciiicc{i}iiiic{d}dddc{i}iiiicc{{d}ii}dc{{i}dd}ic{{d}iii}ddddc{ii}ddc{iiii}iiic{i}dciiic{d}dddciiiicddc{i}dddc{{d}iii}ddddddc{iii}iiic{ddd}dddc{{i}dd}c{d}dddc{i}iiiiicicdddcddddc{{d}iii}c{i}ddc{d}iiic{ii}ddc{iiiiii}iiiiiic{{d}i}dddc{iiiiii}iiiiiciiiicccddddciiiiccc{ii}ddcddc{d}ddddddc{i}iiiiiicc{d}ddddddc{ii}ddc{dd}iicc{i}iiiiiic{d}ddddddcc{i}iiiiiic{d}ddddddc{ii}ddcc{dd}ddccc{ii}iic{dd}iicddddcciiiic{ii}ddc{dd}ddciiiicddddcc{ii}iicddc{d}ddddddc{ii}ddc{dd}iicccddddciiiiccc{ii}ddc{dd}ddccc{ii}iicddc{d}ddddddcc{i}iiiiiic{d}ddddddc{ii}ddc{dd}iiccddddc{ii}iic{dd}iiccc{i}iiiiiic{d}ddddddc{i}iiiiiiciic{{d}i}iiic{iiii}c{dddd}c{{i}ddd}dddc{i}dc{d}dc{ii}ddcc{{d}ii}dddc{iiii}c{iiiii}ic{d}dciiiiic{dd}ic{i}cdddcddddddc{{d}iii}iiic{{i}dd}iiicic{dd}ic{ii}dc{d}dcddddddc{{d}iii}iiic{{i}dd}iiiiiic{d}iiicddddddcdddddc{{d}iii}iic{{i}dd}dddc{d}ddc{i}ddciiiiic{{d}iii}c{iiii}iiic{iii}iiicddc{d}iciiiiic{d}iiic{d}ddciiciiiic{ddddd}ddddddc{{i}dd}iic{dddd}c{iiii}ddcddddddcic{d}dddddc{i}ddc{dddddd}dddc{iiii}ic{ii}iiiiciiicddddddc{d}iic{{d}iii}iiicic{i}dddc{ii}ddc{iiiiii}iiiiiicc{{d}ii}ddc{iiiii}ddc{dddd}ddddddcc{ii}dddc{dd}iiic{iiii}iiiiiic{ddd}icc{dd}ic{ii}dc{dd}iiiccccc{i}iiiiicc{iii}iiic{ddd}dddc{d}dddddcc{i}iiiiic{d}dddddccc{iiiii}ddc{ddd}dc{dd}iiicic{i}iiiiiiccc{dd}iciiic{i}iiiiiicc{d}ddddddccdddccc{iiiii}ddc{dddd}dddddc{i}iiiiiic{iii}ic{ddd}dddcccc{d}ddddcdddccciiicdccccccic{i}iiiicc{d}dddddcic{i}iiiiiicccc{dd}iciiic{d}ddddciic{iiii}ddc{iii}dc{i}dddcciiic{{d}iii}iiic{d}ddc{iiiii}iiiiic{ii}iiiiciiicddddddc{d}iic{{d}iii}iiicic{{i}dd}dddc{i}iiic{{d}i}ddc{ii}iiiiiic{iiii}dciiiiic{i}iiiic{d}dddddc{i}iiic{i}dc{dd}ddddc{i}iicdciiiiiic{d}dddddc{i}dciiiiiic{dddddd}iic{dd}ddddc{iiii}ddc{iii}dc{i}dddcciiic{{d}iii}iiic{d}ddc{iiiii}iiiiic{ii}iiiiciiicddddddc{d}iic{{d}iii}iiicicddc{iiii}c{d}dddc{iiii}iic{dddd}ddc{ii}ic{ddd}dc{i}ciiiiic{dd}iiic{i}iic{iii}ddc{ddd}iic{iiiii}iic{ddddd}ddc{d}ddc{iiiiii}ic{ddddd}icc{iiiii}iic{ddddd}ddc{ii}iic{ddd}ddddc{{i}ddd}dddc{ddddd}dddddc{iiiii}dc{ddddd}ic{iiii}ic{dddd}dc{d}ic{i}dc{ii}ic{ddd}ddc{d}ddddddc{i}ddcdcdcdc{ii}icdc{iii}iiiiiic{dddddd}c{{i}d}iiicdcdcddc{{d}iii}ddc{iii}iiiiiic{iii}iiiicdcdc{{d}iii}dddcdc{iii}iiiiiicdc{iii}iiiicdcdcdcddc{{d}iii}ddc{iii}iiiiiic{iii}iiiicdcdcddc{ii}iic{dddddd}iicddccddc{dd}iic{ii}dddcdc{ii}dddc{dd}icdc{dd}ic{ii}dddc{iii}iiiic{ddddd}ddddc{iiiii}icc{ddd}ddddddc{iii}iiiicdc{iii}dddc{dddddd}ddddc{iii}iiic{ii}iic{dddddd}ic{iiiiii}dddc{dddd}c{dd}ic{iii}iiic{ddd}dddddcdcdcdcdc{{i}ddd}iiiiic{dddd}ddcdcdcddc{iiiiii}dcddccddc{{d}iii}ddddddc{iiii}ddc{ii}ddc{dddd}ddc{iiii}c{ii}dddcddc{dddddd}icddc{iiiiii}dc{dd}ic{dd}c{dd}ddddc{{i}dd}dddc{ddddd}c{iiiii}ddc{{d}ii}ic{ii}iic{iii}iiiiiic{ddd}ddc{ddd}ic{ii}icdc{iii}iiiiiic{ddd}ddc{ddd}c{iiiiii}dc{iii}iiiccdcddc{{d}iii}ddc{iii}iiiiiic{iii}iiiic{dddd}iiiccddc{ddddd}ic{{i}dd}dddc{d}ddc{i}ddciiiiic{{d}iii}cic{{i}dd}iic{d}dciiiiicdcdc{{d}iii}dddddcddddddc{iiii}ddc{iii}dc{i}dddcciiic{{d}iii}iiic{d}ddc{iiiii}iiiiic{i}iiiiiciiiciiic{d}iiic{dddd}dddc{d}dccc{{i}ddd}cddc{d}ddddc{i}iiicic{{d}iii}iic{iiiii}ic{i}dcddddddciiiic{i}ic{d}ddc{dddddd}iiic{iiiii}iiic{i}ic{d}ddc{ii}ddc{d}iic{d}iic{i}dciiiiiicdc{{d}iii}iic{iiiii}iiiiiic{i}ddc{d}ddddddc{ii}ic{d}dddddc{i}iiiicic{{d}iii}ic{iiiiii}dc{d}ic{ii}ic{dd}dc{ddddd}c{iiiiii}ddciiiiic{d}cic{ii}dc{{d}iii}ddddc{iiiiii}ddc{i}iic{d}iiicdc
```